# How to hide comments from private posts on user dashboard

Tags: wp-admin

Any ways to hide all comments from private post on `User => Dash Board => Comment` ?

Comment: What you mean with user dashboard, the default dashboard page in the back end area? In this area is only a count of comments, not a relation to private posts. Also only page have the status of private, so maybe you have an plugin active to add this function of private posts?

Comment: Yes, my mean is user dashboard page in back end erea. I im writing a plugin accept researchers can create they own private articts, and use comment template as a note featured. I also need to hide all comments  in they own private posts for any members.